# Auto upload app on App Store using Jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I would like to upload app using Jenkins on Mac. I had tried with Relution Enterprise Appstore Publisher plugin but getting below error while uploading app.

```
[MultiRequestUploader] Error uploading file (502), server's response:

<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>daiquiri/2.0.0</center>
</body>
</html>


[MultiRequestUploader] Upload of asset failed.
[Builds] Changing build result from SUCCESS to UNSTABLE
[MultiRequestUploader] Upload of build artifacts failed.
[ArtifactFileUploader] Closing connection…
[ArtifactFileUploader] Connection closed
[Builds] Changing build result from SUCCESS to UNSTABLE
```

Build step 'Deploy to Relution Enterprise Appstore' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE

Please let me know if is there any other plugin available